# Hover Effect when over image

Tags: html, css

I think my classes or ID's are messed up when I try to call it.

***CSS:***

```
image#ply : hover .ply-text {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

***HTML:***

```
<image id="ply" style="height: 50px; padding:5px;" src="images.png">
        <div class="ply-text">
            <p>Click for more info!</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: no spaces should be in `image#ply : hover`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues first:

- The HTML element for embedding images is called `img`.
- An [`img` element's content model is empty](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/embedded-content-1.html#the-img-element), i.e. it may not have any child elements.
- Even if those were not issues, you would not see the effect you're looking for since the text is already visible at the start.

Given that, here's a possible solution:

```css
.ply-text {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#ply:hover ~ .ply-text {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

The `~` is a [sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) that allows one to refer to an element following another.

Answer (score 0):

Images use an `<img>` tag (not 'image') - that's important to note (as it hasn't been commented on so far). As remarked, you should remove the space between the id and the `:hover` in your css.

I would advise you remove the inline style and use css or at least add it into your id style/ add extra attributes as a class in the head of the body (css is better!).

In the style, you don't need image/img before the definition of your id, you can just leave `#ply{your style}` on it's own.

If you want to display the pic on hover,  I would use display:block/none instead. Visibility just shows it if it's hidden. (I've done so in the snippet, run and see if it's the desired effect).  Also, use an alt tag! I added one. If you want to show/hide the text you could use either but first you have to set the visibility to hidden or display to none... I added a class for ply-text on its own for this.

So your code would read

```css
#ply {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.ply-text{
   display:none; /* or visibility:hidden*/
}
#ply:hover +.ply-text{
   display:block; /* or visibility:visible*/
}
```

```html
<img id="ply" src="images.png" alt="plyimage">
<div class="ply-text">
  <p>Click for more info!</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps